# belongsToMany Laravel - find()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estou desenvolvendo uma Intranet que vai contemplar **Categorias** e **Posts**. Um post pode receber "n" categorias.

Para tal efeito estou usando *belongsToMany()*.

O problema está ao retornar esses dados com **Post::find($idpost)**, ele retorna não somente 1 registro mas todos os registros de post em que a tabela **pivot** está relacionada.

Não encontrei nada do tipo e não sei se estou fazendo algo errado.

O **create** está sendo executado com perfeição, o problema está quando peço para retornar apenas 1 registro.

Eu inseri *belongsToMany()* nas 2 tabelas, **Posts** e **Categorias**.

Alguém poderia me dizer se esse comportamento é normal ou se tem algo errado na lógica/construção?

PS: Laravel 5.2

**EDIT**

**Post**
tabela: posts
pk: id

**Categoria**
tabela: categories
pk:id

**Pivô**
tabela: category_post
pk: id
fk: post_id
fk: category_id

```
namespace App\Intranet;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql_intranet';
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'text', 'categories'];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Intranet\Category');
    }
}



namespace App\Intranet;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql_intranet';
    protected $fillable = ['categoria', 'herdado'];

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Intranet\Post');
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu acho que deveria retornar um registo, só o post com id X

Comment: Pois é, Miguel. Eu tenho 3 registros Posts, id 35, 36 e 39. Qualquer um que testo, ele me retorna todos os Posts. Não somente o ID que quero.

Comment: Confira no model `Post` se está a actuar na tabela certa, `protected $table = ..`

Comment: Se você passar um `array` para `find`, ele vai trazer mais de um valor. Veja se `$idPost` é um `array` ou `int`.

Comment: Eu usei a convenção. Preciso declar mesmo assim? Os nomes das tabelas são: **posts** e **categories**

Comment: o $idPost é inteiro... inclusive testei digitando o valor númerico, sem variável.

Comment: tente colocar o nome da tabela pivô como `category_post` no singular...

Comment: @MarcoGarcia coloque o código dos 2 models, por favor.

Comment: Pronto @RafaelAcioly

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o `hasMany` ao invés do `belongsToMany`.
Seria `belongsToMany` se você fizesse o `SELECT` através da tabela **CategoryPost**.

### Model

```
Post.php

public function categorias(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\CategoryPost', 'post_id');
}
```

### Controller

```
MainController.php

use App\Post;    
public function index(){

    $posts = Post::find(1);    
    dd($posts->categorias);
}
```

Comment: Diego, essa CategoryPost seria a tabela pivot? Mas no caso não existe Model para ela. Está certo?

Comment: Você tem que criar o Model pra essa tabela.

Comment: Diego, não entendi muito bem sua solução. Poderia ser mais específico?

Comment: Cria um Model chamado CategoryPost que é referente a sua tabela Pivot.

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou utilizar o relacionamento `hasManyThrough`? Ele serve exatamente para relacionamento `ManyToMany`, que é o que parece ser o seu caso.

Tem um exemplo completo na documentação do Laravel neste Link abaixo:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Usando `hasManyThrough`, você pode definir o relacionamento em ambos Models e acessar os múltiplos registros relacionados de cada um.

Espero ter ajudado! ;)

Answer (score 0):

A convencao pra pivots é o nome de cada tabela (singular) separado por `_` em ordem alfabetica.

`category_post`

Comment: Entendi, Rafael. Mas no caso meu migration/tabela está configurado com uma tabela pivô. Teria problema nesse sentido, isto é, declarar apenas hasMany() no Post, ao invés de belongsToMany()? Isso não descaracterizaria o conceito da tabela pivô?

Comment: No meu caso, um post pode sim pertencer mais que 1 categoria. Vc está julgando que um post pode ter apenas 1 categoria, o post_id que vc menciona não tem na tb categories.

Comment: quais os nomes dos campos das 2 tabelas que você esta tentando usar o pivô? na tabela post e categoria qual o campo de relacionamento?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, inseri a estrutura basica

Comment: Inseri errado no EDIT. Está no singular.